# How to create new object by two objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested-object

I would like to know how to create new object by two objects in javascript.

iterate through the obj1, and add the obj2 values, create new object in javascript

```
function getObject(obj1, obj2){
  let result={};
  Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key=>{
    if(key==="start" || key==="end"){
      result.time= obj1.start+"-"+obj1.end,
      result.qty= obj2.qty
    }
  }) 

}

var obj1 ={
  start: "16:01", end: "23:59", totalqty: 1065, totalamount: 8229170
}

var obj2 = {
  qty: 10, 
  amt: 120
}
```

Expected Output

```
 {
   time: "16:01-23:59"
   val: 10 // represents obj2.qty,
   totalqty: 1065, 
   totalamount: 8229170,
   price: 120
 }
```

Comment: checkout [Spread syntax ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function and get desired properties:

```js
var obj1 ={
  start: "16:01", end: "23:59", totalqty: 1065, totalamount: 8229170
}

var obj2 = {
  qty: 10,
  amt: 120
}

const merge = (obj1, obj2) => {
  return {
    time: obj1.start + '-' + obj1.end,
    val: obj2.qty,
    totalqty: obj1.totalqty,
    totalamount: obj1.totalamount,
    price: obj2.amt
  };
}

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2));
```

In addition, you can use `spread` syntax, but it merges all properties:

```js
let obj1 ={
  start: "16:01", end: "23:59", totalqty: 1065, totalamount: 8229170
}

let obj2 = {
  qty: 10, 
  amt: 120
}

let merged = {...obj1, ...obj2};
console.log(merged );
```

or try to use `Object.assign()` and it is also merges all properties:

```js
var obj1 ={
  start: "16:01", end: "23:59", totalqty: 1065, totalamount: 8229170
}

var obj2 = {
  qty: 10, 
  amt: 120
}

var result = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(result);
```

[Read more Object.assign() here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: thanks but please check expected output, its different

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure the objects, rename some properties and return a new object.

```js
const
    merge = ({ start, end, totalqty, totalamount }, { qty: val, amt: price }) =>
        ({ time: start + "-" + end, val, totalqty, totalamount, price}),
    obj1 = { start: "16:01", end: "23:59", totalqty: 1065, totalamount: 8229170 },
    obj2 = { qty: 10, amt: 120 };

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2));
```